# Why was Mycroft indifferent about Mary's potential death and the possible consequences of Ajay's reappearance?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, sherlock

In season 4 *Sherlock* clearly says that Ajay is a killer and hints that he could murder Mary, but all Mycroft says is that agents die. Sherlock goes to Mycroft for help. He sees Mary as a friend. He also made a vow.

Mycroft should be interested in the sudden appearance of a guy thought to be dead. I don't understand why Mycroft doesn't see that Ajay may pose a threat. Ajay was tortured and held captive. He knows things. Probably he heard and saw plenty. Maybe he’s working for the enemy. To me it's obvious he might be a threat to both Mycroft and Lady Smallwood. All thay Mycroft does is tell Sherlock you can’t keep all the killers away from her, which I found surprising. No wonder Sherlock angrily says not on my watch.

He knows that Mary is John's wife, a mother and also Sherlock's friend. Mary may be an assaasin, but she's not a baddie. Mary has shown she's on the good side. Sherlock trusts her as does John. Misunderstandings about her behaviour are explained in the series. Lady Smallwood headed AGRA, Mycroft disbanded it. Tbilisi was 6 years ago, the lady proved through her behaviour she’s on the good side. Questioning her can wait. Mycroft allows Ajay to almost kill Mary until the police kill him and Sherlock takes her to London. (Also I think Mycroft knew about Mary’s past, but didn’t want to admit it to Sherlock. Look at his face in that conversation.)

So why is Mycroft so indifferent about the potential threat Ajay poses to Mary?

Comment: You've got multiple questions in the body of your post, and it's unclear which is the one you want the answer to. Would you be able to edit the question to narrow this down to a single, objectively-answerable question?

Comment: Plus some of this is a pointless rant, e.g. "If you can’t be objective don’t answer. I’m tired of internet users besmiriching Mary or Ms.Abbington." Please [**follow the tour**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://Movies.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @BCdotWEB I was going to edit most of that out, to focus on the question, but then I stopped and thought, "Hang on... what *is* the question, exactly?" Hence my request that the OP clarify.

Comment: I just don't want people to be aggressive about Mary or Amanda Abbington, that's all. What multiple questions do you mean? Is that a reason to give -1? I had to explain my line of reasoning. The way I see things is supposed to help people answer, comment or discuss. What's difficult about that?

Comment: I count three: "Shouldn’t Mycroft be interested in the sudden appearance of a guy thought to be dead?", "I think Mycroft knew about Mary’s past, but didn’t want to admit it to Sherlock. What do you think?", and "Doesn’t Ajay pose a threat?" I wasn't the downvoter, but yes, "this question is unclear" is a valid reason to downvote.

Comment: That's so complicated that it deserves a downvote? In conversations in real life people ask questions because they think aloud. Not every single question needs to be answered. Some questions are there to help people think about the issue at hand. How would people feel if I started to downvote their question because I thought it uniteresting I wonder. What do you think is clearly a direct address. I made changes.

Comment: "How would people feel if I started to downvote their question because I thought it uniteresting I wonder." - That's your prerogative. You can vote how you wish. "This question is not useful" is actually a valid downvote reason in its own right. However, I should note that a) downvotes don't count unless you have a certain amount of reputation, as an anti-trolling measure, and b) revenge-downvoting is strongly frowned upon.

Comment: Okay people, so I tried to clean this question up a little and streamline the thoughts a little more. To Kat, noone downvoted it because it was un*interesting* rather than un*clear*, there's a big difference between those. But to F1Krazy and the others, there really aren't that many questions in this and it's quite clear that they're all connected to one single point, I got that even without having seen that season (or just not remembering it anymore). Okay, to BCDotWEB's defense there were some weird parts in the question, but they have been removed by the asker quite a while  ago...

Comment: ...On the bottom line, this thing is a reasonable and valid question now that neither will be closed nor deserves downvotes really. In general, it would have profited from editing earlier more than downvoting because there were two many question marks in the next. But hopefully its score will normalize over time.

Comment: @F1Krazy One specific remark to your point a), though. Downvotes *very much* count, disregarding of anyone's reputation, because they're about the *question*, not the asker. Having your question downvoted when you think it is allright is a) still unfortunate even if it has no effect on your reputation and can b) still be unhealthy for the community if it was unjustified.

Comment: I'm not saying the downvotes here were entirely unjustified based on the previous versions of the question, but the fact that noone's reputation gets influenced is certainly not an excuse for downvoting willy-nilly, especially when very few people really take the time to reconsider their votes on revised questions.

Comment: I've made so many changes and got help from others that I hope things will improve. My point was that I don't want to see users bashing Mary as a character or Ms. Abbington as an actress. The scene when Sherlock was shot has already been explained even here as was the point about Mary being an assassin, so I didn't want haters to activate their hatred under my question. I just wanted to draw users' attention to a point I found bizzare. I saw Sherlock 4 in 2017, but found  this website recently. I read  questions and answers on here when I didn't have an account and decided to  open one.

Comment: I really don't know why anyone would bash the actress playing her, this certainly wouldn't make for a reasonable or even relevant answer. Nor do I think people would be bashing Mary either. But you also have to understand that saying someone is an assassin isn't "bashing" when she actually *is* an assassin. Disagreeing with an answer isn't a reason to take it as a personal insult to the character or even her actress. In any case, such considerations really have no place in the question and if you see problematic comments bashing anyone, feel free to flag them.

Comment: However, I'd also prefer you wouldn't continuously add more sentences to the question to make it more confusing and overblown again. It's clear people have been confused by it and a lot of fluff has been stripped from it in the hopes of streamlining it a bit better to the core of the matter about Mary and Ajay that you're after. Maybe give it some rest. So no, you really ought not to care about anyone's opinion about the look on Mycroft's face, because it contributes nothing to this question. At some point this site isn't an open discussion forum or a place for loose brainstorming either.

Comment: Ms. Abbington received death threats on Twitter and there were newspaper articles about it. Mary was subject to hate on tumblr as well. I know she was an assassin. The point is it doesn't have to be a bad thing. It depends on what side you're on. I'm not emotional about it. I just want internet users to see that Mary isn't the type of assassin who is evil. John and Sherlock uses guns too an lie in the series. Fictional characters and humans do many things. It's the reason or the motive that counts.

Comment: Well, okay, I didn't know that. Social media can be terrible and especially nerds whose favourite show got "ruined" by anyone or whatever. However, on this site we don't condone any such hating. That is inherent to how this place works and if something like that pops up, it will be dealt with.

Comment: I admit that maybe my comment intially was too long, but it was a result of reading all sorts of stuff online. I don't deny Mary was an assassin, but since she works for Mycroft in the 'Victorian' bit and is employed by Lady S,we can assume she's not the type of killer who'd work for Bond's Blofeld, which would be Moriarty's 'servant' in the world of Sherlock Holmes. Then when I saw what the users here were like I made changes. Mary helps John and Sherlock. In the Sign of Four when Holmes says that Miss Morstan would be good at what they do. She wants a family, but the past comes to her.